# How to create an array of CommandButtons and assign ComboBoxes which exist on a Form?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing VBA on a Microsof Excel workbook. I created a form with 5 CommandButtons and I am trying to assign these CommandButtons to an array of CommandButtons I created. I try to make this assignment by pasing the array as parameter to a function and I make a call to this function, in the Workbook_Open event as shown below:

```
Dim Buttons(5) As CommandButton

Public Function InitializeButtons(ButtonArray() As CommandButton)
   ButtonArray(0) = TableForm.CommandButton1
   ButtonArray(1) = TableForm.CommandButton2
   ButtonArray(2) = TableForm.CommandButton3
   ButtonArray(3) = TableForm.CommandButton4
   ButtonArray(4) = TableForm.CommandButton5
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   void = InitializeButtons(Buttons)
End Sub
```

The problem is that for some reason this assignment takes never plays, because I get the following error message:

Run-time errror '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set.

In case you have any ideas or suggestions in how this problem could be solved, please let me know.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Set when assigning object variables

```
Set ButtonArray(0) = TableForm.CommandButton1
```

Comment: Hello Tim. Thank you very much for your instant answer. I couldn't think of any solution, but you were a great help. Thank you once again.